# Creating a Dark background Theme in android

Tags: android

I am making a option for user to choose themes from two themes.Actually i use **AppTheme** as app default theme.There a option for user to switch between two themes **Light** and **Dark**. When user chooses **Dark** theme it should change to **MyThemeDark** from default theme **Apptheme** .

My **style.xml** is

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#009688</item>
</style>

<style name="MyThemeDark" parent="MyTheme.Dark"></style>

<style name="MyTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#009688</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/Background</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/Background</item>
</style>
```

And in color.xml

```
<color name="Background">#363F45</color>
```

in my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Themes are changing correctly.But my problem is while changing to **MyThemeDark** the background color is not changing to dark color rather it remains white. How can i fix this problem?

I want theme like this photo

https://goo.gl/photos/F95fm7NQWCGGNa9g6

Comment: What is the value of `@color/Background`? Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml` and the activity layout XML.

Comment: Without enough code, nobody can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command in XML file, within layout tag to change color it so simple
for example for Relative layout:

```
<Relativelayout
android:background="#000000"> </Relativelayout>
```

Also, You can use simple color resources, specified usually inside res/values/colors.xml

```
<color
name="red">#ffff0000</color>
```

or get it in code via:

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.red)
```